# ¿Como registrar notificaciones push en Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, push-notification

Las notificaciones push en versiones anteriores a Xcode8, funcionaban correctamente, pero al migrar a swift 3 ya no registra el Token.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil));
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

**¿Cómo registrar las notificaciones push en Swift 3?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que importar el framework `UserNotifications` y añadir el delegado `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` en el fichero AppDelegate.swift

**Solicitar permiso al usuario**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
     let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
     center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
     }
     application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
     return true
}
```

**Obtener el Token**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print(deviceTokenString)
}
```